# How find the numbers in input value and hide are numbers with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have input like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" 1154 Update "  class="btn-success">
```

i need a find any numbers in `Value` and hide this numbers like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" Update "  class="btn-success">
```

thanks for your help....

Comment: **hide** or **remove**?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML Part :

```
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" 1154 Update " class="btn-success">
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" 1155 Update " class="btn-success">
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" 1156 Update " class="btn-success">
```

And jQuery Part :

```
$('input[type="submit"]').val($('input[type="submit"]').val().replace(/\d+/g, "").trim());
```

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pimplesushant/a5ekLhab/4/) might help you.

If you want to hide it. You can set any data attribute to the submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="starts" data-id ="1154" value="Update " class="btn-success">
```

Answer (score 1):

> i need a find any numbers in Value and hide this numbers

You can use `setAttribute`

```
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][name="starts"]');
var value = button.getAttribute( "value" );
button.setAttribute( "value", value.replace(/\d+/g, "") ); //use trim if required
```

**Demo**

```js
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][name="starts"]');
var value = button.getAttribute("value");
button.setAttribute("value", value.replace(/\d+/g, "")); //use trim if required
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="starts" value=" 1154 Update " class="btn-success">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to replace the numbers.
I have applied both [Keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) and [Change](https://api.jquery.com/Change/) events.

```js
$("#inputRegex").change(function()
{
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\d+/g, ''))
});

$("#inputRegex").keyup(function()
{
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\d+/g, ''))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputRegex" />
```

Comment: With my input not work <input type="submit" id="inputRegex" value=" 763 Update">

Comment: Its working fine for me, Can you give me your code updated?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to hide those numbers on click on submit button:

```
$(":submit").click(function() {
  string value =  $(this).val().toString();
  value = $.trim(value.replace(/\d+/g, ""));
  $(this).val(value);

});
```

if you want to hide on load:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(":submit").each(function() {
      string value =  $(this).val().toString();
      value = $.trim(value.replace(/\d+/g, ""));
      $(this).val(value);

        });
})
```

this will remove all the numbers in values of all input type submit.
here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6y64jcc/)

Comment: Can you run in JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: I want hide for users but in backend not change , can i ?

Comment: It's possible using the button element.

`<button name="name" value=" 234 Update " type="submit">Update</button>`

Comment: You can set any data attribute to the submit button e.g. <input type="submit" name="starts" data-id ="1154" value="Update " class="btn-success">

Comment: Thanks my friends i fix that with Button ;)